# Non-linear non-homogeneous first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to find the solution to the following ODE:

$$
(y'(x))^2 - \left(\frac{y(x)}{\epsilon}\right)^2 + f(x)^2 = 0,
$$
where $f(x)$ is some given function and I want to solve for $y(x)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Write the differential equation as $$y'(x) = \pm \sqrt{y(x)^2/\epsilon^2 - f(x)^2}$$

To speak of "the solution" rather than "a solution", you'll need to specify an initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0$.  I'm assuming you want real solutions, so $y_0^2/\epsilon^2 - f(x_0)^2$ had better not be negative.  Also you should specify
whether you want $+$ or $-$ (a solution can switch from one to the other, but only when the square root is $0$).

There's no hope of a closed-form solution with $f$ left as an arbitrary function.  Even for very simple $f$ such as $f(x)=x$,
I don't think there are closed-form solutions.  But for particular $f$ and particular initial condition you'll be able to find numerical solutions.  You should be aware that the solutions are likely to stop existing $y^2/\epsilon^2 - f(x)^2$ hits $0$ and threatens to become negative.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer. I'm actually only interested in a solution for y(x) to lowest order in $\epsilon$. I'm hoping to find that $y(x) = \epsilon f(x) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)$. Do you have an idea how to show that?

Comment: Formally, when $f(x) \ne 0$ and is sufficiently differentiable there does seem to be a solution
$$ y(x) = f(x) \epsilon + \frac{f'(x)^2}{2 f(x)} \epsilon^3 + \left( \frac{f''(x) f'(x)^2}{f(x)^2} - \frac{5 f'(x)^4}{8 f(x)^3}\right) \epsilon^5 + \ldots $$

Comment: Thank you! Did you find it by hand or with Mathematica?